# Excel formula to link specific cells from one row to another and calculate mean/standard dev/mode

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Basically, I am looking for a function that allows me to determine the standard deviation, mean, and mode for one TA's marks for a specific assignment. Each row specifies which TA is grading, and so I need a function that will choose all of TA 'A's students, take the corresponding marks for paper 1 from each of the rows, and calculate the standard deviation, mean, and mode. I have tried IF functions combined with LOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH but it is hard to come up with an equation that is general enough.

The top half of the photo is the first sheet, where you can see that each TA (A, B, C, or D) adds in the grades for the first paper, second paper, third paper, etc. I need a function that will take all of TA 'A''s grades for paper 1 and show me the standard deviation, mean and mode on the second sheet seen in the lower half of the photo. I need to do this for all TAs and all of the sections of marks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use array formulas. For the mean, you could use the AVERAGEIFS formula, but since the other two don't have a similar formula, you might as well use array formulas for all three.

To make an array formula, you'll want to press **ctrl+shift+enter** (command+enter for mac) once you're done entering the formula. You'll know you have done it right if there are curly brackets {} around your formula.

The following formulas are for TA 'A' and essay #1. You'll want to modify the range so it fits your data.

For sd: =STDEV.S(IF(D2:D100="A",G2:G100,""))

For mode: =MODE.SNGL(IF(D2:D100="A",G2:G100,""))

For mean: =AVERAGE(IF(D2:D100="A",G2:G100,""))